# how to tell when a HTTP web page has changed when it is of type html/text?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, last-modified

I'm trying to work out the algorithm to tell if non-binary files on the web have changed or not.  I was going to go with:

- LastModified datetime from header, and then if these aren't present fallback to
- ContentLength from header

I'm finding however that for alot of websites the LastModified for the HTML pages are actually just using the current DateTime, hence the approach doesn't work (i.e. would lead to an indication that the page is always changing) I think...?

What would be a good algorithm then?  How about?

```
IF response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html")  <== or should this just be "text"
  THEN: 
    Check based on comparing text content before & after
  ELSE: 
    IF LastModified dates are OK 
      Compare based on LastModified dates
    ELSE 
      Compare based on ContentLength
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending the request, specify If-Modified-Since http header. Then it's up to the server to reply either with new html or with 304 - content not changed.

Comment: Is this for both text (eg web site front pages) as well as binary files?

Comment: Also do most websites/web servers adhere to this in general?

Comment: Yes, most websites use the header, because AFAIK the typical browser uses information from cache in case the content didn't change. This decreases server load immensely.

Answer (score 0):

The ETag response header is a good indicator of this, if present. Use requests with If-None-Match (or just HEAD requests) to see.