# How to reduce latency while retrieving RSS feeds using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a requirement to consume only the latest two rss feeds (using .NET) to reduce latency in reading RSS.  I found plenty of examples to consume RSS.  However, I did not find any to limit the feeds being read.  And, this is not for a windows forms application.

Comment: Do you want to reduce latency in reading the feed directly from it's source, or reduce the time it takes to iterate through the items in the feed? Since RSS is XML formatted, IMHO you'll have to download the file from its source before you can open it as an XML document and pick the first two items.

Comment: You don't have to download whole file.  Read below.

Comment: You don't have to download the file at all. Read below(er).

Comment: You don't have to use RSS. Read below(est). (Sorry, couldn't resist) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the http connection to the RSS URL and load the stream by hand, reading it entry by entry at a time, and then, when you had enough, terminate connection.  You don't have to go all the way for whole XML.

Of course, some light XML parsing would be needed here.

Comment: I am not implying to read whole feed.  I want him to BREAK the connection when he had enough data.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that's not even necessary. HTTP-Last-Modified is all that is needed.

Comment: "...some light XML parsing would be needed here."  But couldn't he just create an `XmlReader` on the stream?  He could terminate the connection any time.  The reader doesn't need to load the whole thing into memory.

Comment: @Jim - good hack, great idea, guess it's worth investigating - though, all the buffering and stuff?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know how much buffering would be involved.  It's probably a moot point, anyway, as it's likely that making the connection to the web server will take just as long as (or perhaps longer than) downloading the document.

Comment: @Jim - you are right - only in some extremes if someone generates one-mile-long RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are really just web pages. You could check the [HTTP Last-Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781579/how-to-tell-when-a-http-web-page-has-changed-when-it-is-of-type-html-text) headers on all your feeds' URLs, then download the most recently updated ones. Be aware, though, you could starve your less-frequently updated feeds in this manner, especially if you have two feeds that update frequently in your set.

Here's an article on the matter: [HTTP Conditional Get for RSS Hackers](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2002/10/21/http_conditional_get_for_rss_hackers/).